# ETL Data from NoSQL to Relational

Tags: relational-database, etl, nosql

What are typical ways that people would ETL data from a NoSQL database to a relational one? I'm interested to use some BI tools with a relational DB. I know that I could use an ODBC driver with NoSQL but wondering the steps or tools that could do the ETL into a relational database(MySQL, Postgres).

Comment: Which NoSQL product are you using?

Comment: I'm not posting this as an answer, because I've never used mongodb and can't guarantee that it will work in your scenario. I think you'd be well served by Foreign Data Wrappers (FDW) for PostgreSQL. A web search "postgresql fdw mongodb" turns up many suggestions. Here is one with a good worked example. http://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-plus-edb-blog/jason-davis/tales-trenches-new-mongodb-fdw